# Flask run not working when running it on powershell

Tags: python, flask

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.

I am trying to run flask as I am just starting to learn about back end but I cant seem to solve this problem. Please help

Comment: did you read error message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check you working directory, you should be in the same directory that your flask app is, you can use `cd c:/path/to/app` to change directory or hold `shift` and right click in that directory and choose `open powershell here`.

Also it is better to rename your app to `app.py`, flask will run it by default, otherwise you should set `FLASK_APP` variable with `$env:FLASK_APP = "app_name.py"`

Comment: Thank you so much @BSimjoo it worked all I had to do was to rename my app to app.py. Much love